# Vuex can't stop setInteval

Tags: vuex, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a method in Vuex:

```
export const startTime = ({ commit, state }, status) => {
    let timeInterval
    
    if(status) {
        const timer = 1000
        timeInterval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('x')
            commit('SET_RUNNED_TIME', parseInt(state.runnedTime += timer))
        }, timer)
    }
    else {
        console.log('y')
        clearInterval(timeInterval)
        commit('SET_RUNNED_TIME', 0)
    }
}
```

From my component I send value `true` or `false` to method `startTime()`. When I send `true` then method run commit `SET_RUNNED_TIME`. But when I send `false` `clearInterval(timeInterval)` not stopping `setInterval` and still is sending `commit('SET_RUNNED_TIME' ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `timeInterval` is inside the scope of the function. If you want it to keep on living between different calls to `startTime` you need to put it outside the function scope. For example in the state.

Comment: Yes, I moved `timeInterval` to `state` and now `clearInterval` work correctly.